# Is my integration solution right or solution by site is right?

Tags: integration

I was solving some online integral quiz and my answer came completely different than site. Explanation seems erroneous but I doubt if I am not able to understand it. Following is my solution and then image is screen shot of solution by site.

> $\int x \ln (x/e^x) dx   $ setting $\ln x = y$ then
>
> $\int (e^y)^2 (y-e^y)dy$ solving this will result
>
> $(e^y)^2 (y-\frac 32)$ that can be again written in x as
>
> $x^2(\ln x - \frac32)$

site's answer:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the solution changed $x$ into $\frac1x$ in the equality

$$\int x\ln\frac{x}{e^x} dx = \int\color{red}{\frac{1}{x}}(\ln x - \ln e^x)$$

when they should really get

$$\int x\ln\frac{x}{e^x} dx = \int \color{blue}x(\ln x - \ln e^x)$$

Comment: $dy = \frac 1x dx$ this x went other side so one more $e^y$ came in integration

Comment: @Tab Oh yeah. I'll rewrite the answer, sorry for that.

Comment: @Tab See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks so my answer is right

Comment: @Tab Yeah, it looks like the solution made a typo :).